# What is the difference between calling ViewModelProvider(Activity) and ViewModelProvider(Fragment)?

Tags: android

If I want to get an Instance of a ViewModel shared between an activity and multiple fragments which of these should I use? Also from which fragment lifecycle callback would be appropriate to call these methods and why?

Comment: `ViewModelProvider(Activity).get(..)` will be tied up to lifecycle of the activity while `ViewModelProvider(Fragment).get` will be tied up to the lifecycle of the fragment. It will exist till the activity / fragment is alive respectively. So if u wanna share same viewmodels within an activity with the fragments, u should use activity viewModel not fragment viewModel.

Comment: From which fragment lifecycle callback would be appropriate to call these methods and why?